# What is the name of the "onload" event?

Tags: jquery

I've a textarea that has `keyup` event to show a preview of rendered input. However, I want to display the same preview immediately after the element is loaded.

```
$('textarea[name="ay[description]"]').on('keyup', function(e){
```

The simplest of all is to initiate `.trigger('keyup')` at the end of the declaration. However, isn't there event such as `load`, `onload` or `ready` that I've missed under different name?

Comment: The ready event on the document could be used.  Just refactor the display code so you can invoke both in the keyup handler and when the document is ready.

Comment: It's very hard to understand what is being asked here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The onLoad event is known as "load" but it only fires for certain objects / elements (iframes, window, document).

> The load event is sent to an element when it and all sub-elements have
>   been completely loaded. This event can be sent to any element
>   associated with a URL: images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the
>   window object.

*http://api.jquery.com/load-event/*

Comment: Therefore, my question is if there is a way to trigger the same event for `textarea`?

Comment: Nope. That event will never work for a textarea. Per the quote above, this event *can be sent* to ... -- it can't be sent to other elements.

Comment: Well, it would be a nice feature to have (addressed to jQuery dev team).

Answer (score 0):

The ready event on the document could be used. Just refactor the display code so you can invoke both in the keyup handler and when the document is ready.  Extend this as necessary for other events (such as 'change', if you need to handle copy/paste).

```
function previewText( input, display )
{
     // do the preview of the input element in the display div
}

$(function() {
    previewText($('textarea[name="ay[description]"]'),$('#ay-preview'));

    $('textarea[name="ay[description]"]').on('keyup change',function() {
         previewText($(this),$('#ay-preview'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to render the preview after each keyup AND initially when the page has finished loading. You van do this:

```
$(document).ready(render);
$('textarea[name="ay[description]"]')
.on('keyup', render);

var render = function() {
  // DO render stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE**

The OP pointed out that, unless otherwise noted, a namespaced event isn't always necessary. Very true:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $aydesc = $('textarea[name="ay[description]"]'),
        $goeshere = $('#goeshere');

    $aydesc.on('keyup.preview', function(e){
        $goeshere.text($(this).val());
    });

    $aydesc.trigger('keyup');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r8Qvz/4/

I don't necessarily suggest that you always need namespaced events to do achieve this, so I updated by answer.

I think you might find a [namespaced event](http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events) useful if you have multiple `keyup` handlers on that element:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $aydesc = $('textarea[name="ay[description]"]'),
        $goeshere = $('#goeshere');

    $aydesc.on('keyup.preview', function(e){
        $goeshere.text($(this).val());
    });

    $aydesc.trigger('keyup.preview');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r8Qvz/3

Namespaced events are pretty nifty, I think.

Of course, you could do it the non-nifty way:

(This has been fixed, it wasn't working previously.)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $aydesc = $('textarea[name="ay[description]"]'),
        $goeshere = $('#goeshere');

    var preview = function(e){
        $goeshere.text($(this).val());
    };

    $aydesc.on('keyup', preview);

    preview.call($aydesc);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r8Qvz/5/

If you have multiple `textarea`s, let me know and I'll update it to manage that case. If you do, you'll need some logic as to which `textarea` value should be shown, unless each `textarea` has it's own display target.

Comment: You can attach the `.trigger` event immediately to the declaration of the `keyup` event. Furthermore, the naming convention for the variables that you are using is alien to javascript, especially the `$` prefix.

Comment: Hmm... Well, that's certainly true, except that what I'm pointing out is that you can give a name to a specific event handler; who knows if you have others, and just want to fire that one specifically. I suppose it will vary if you find that useful (like you say, `$.trigger('keyup')` will work in many cases), but my demonstrations work (let me know otherwise). Additionally, I use `$` to denote variables which are jQuery objects. I wouldn't call it "alien", and it's beside the point anyway, but I've seen it done by others I respect, which is where I got it from.